# PowerPoint: Animate arrow between rectantgle

Tags: animation, ms-office, powerpoint

I'm not sure whether it is the right place to ask a PowerPoint question. So, if it isn't, don't be too harsh with me, please.

I have two rectangles created using the drawing tools on a ppt slide. These both rectangles are connected using an arrow with magnetic connectors.
Now I want to move first one of the rectangles using an animation and in a second step the other one.

That's easy so far.

But now I also want that the magentic connectors stay tied to the rectangles during the animation.

Is this possible somehow?

(I'm unfortunately not sure whether I always use the correct ppt terms above, since I only have a German installation of ppt.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easy solution as the connector won't move with an animation of the connecting shape.

However, if the required movement isn't to complex you could try to replicate the behavior with a set of animations:

1. Move rectangle using motion path
2. Grow connector shape horizontally or vertically
3. Move connector in the required direction using another motion path which must be adjusted to growth rate of the grow animation

All animations need to start simultaneously ("start with previous") and smooth start/end need to be set to 0 sec for the motion paths. A sample of the stretch effect (2.+3.) can be found here: http://pptheaven.mvps.org/experimental.html ("Zoom Test").